# Not able set map value with pair type key

Tags: c++, dictionary, compiler-errors, stl

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
class NodePoint {
  public:
  int x, y;
  NodePoint (int i, int j){x=i; y=j;}
  NodePoint (){}
  bool operator == (const NodePoint &rhs) { return (x == rhs.x && y == rhs.y); };
  bool operator != (const NodePoint &rhs) { return (x != rhs.x || y != rhs.y); };
};
class Link {
  public:
  Link (){}
};
int main() {
  vector < vector <NodePoint> > nodes;
  map < pair < NodePoint, NodePoint > , Link > node_links;
  int sol_row_size = 10, sol_col_size = 10, i, j;
  for(i=0; i<sol_row_size; i++) {
    vector < NodePoint > tn;
    for(j=0; j<sol_col_size; j++) tn.push_back(NodePoint(i,j));
    nodes.push_back(tn);
  }
  for(i=0; i<sol_row_size; i++) {
    for(j=0; j<(sol_col_size-1); j++) {
      node_links[make_pair(nodes[i][j], nodes[i][j+1])] = Link();
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

In the above program I am just trying create a map called `node_links` for which the key will be a pair of 2 input nodes, but I am getting a huge amount of compilation error (and none point some lines in my code) and I am not much used to cpp, any help? What am I doing wrong?

Compilation error below:

```
$ g++ temp.cpp -o temp;
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:61,
                 from temp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h: In function ‘bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = NodePoint, _T2 = NodePoint]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236:22:   instantiated from ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:452:2:   instantiated from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>, _Tp = Link, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>, Link> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Link, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>]’
temp.cpp:35:55:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x.std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>::second < __y.std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>::second’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:207:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1290:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:866:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:899:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_multimap.h:817:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__y.std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>::first < __x.std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>::first’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:207:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1290:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:866:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:899:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_multimap.h:817:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘__x.std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>::first < __y.std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>::first’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: note: candidates are:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:207:5: note: template<class _T1, class _T2> bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:291:5: note: template<class _Iterator> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_Iterator>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_iterator.h:341:5: note: template<class _IteratorL, class _IteratorR> bool std::operator<(const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorL>&, const std::reverse_iterator<_IteratorR>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_vector.h:1290:5: note: template<class _Tp, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&, const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_tree.h:866:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Val, class _KeyOfValue, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::_Rb_tree<_Key, _Val, _KeyOfValue, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:899:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_multimap.h:817:5: note: template<class _Key, class _Tp, class _Compare, class _Alloc> bool std::operator<(const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&, const std::multimap<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>&)
```

UPDATE 1

I have added the following to the NodePOint class

```
bool operator < (const NodePoint &rhs) {
    return (x < rhs.x || (x == rhs.x && y < rhs.y));
};
```

and I am getting the following error:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_algobase.h:65:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/4.6/vector:61,
                 from temp.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h: In function ‘bool std::operator<(const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&, const std::pair<_T1, _T2>&) [with _T1 = NodePoint, _T2 = NodePoint]’:
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_function.h:236:22:   instantiated from ‘bool std::less<_Tp>::operator()(const _Tp&, const _Tp&) const [with _Tp = std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>]’
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_map.h:452:2:   instantiated from ‘std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type& std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::operator[](const key_type&) [with _Key = std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>, _Tp = Link, _Compare = std::less<std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint> >, _Alloc = std::allocator<std::pair<const std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>, Link> >, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::mapped_type = Link, std::map<_Key, _Tp, _Compare, _Alloc>::key_type = std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>]’
temp.cpp:37:55:   instantiated from here
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: error: passing ‘const NodePoint’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool NodePoint::operator<(const NodePoint&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: error: passing ‘const NodePoint’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool NodePoint::operator<(const NodePoint&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/stl_pair.h:209:62: error: passing ‘const NodePoint’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘bool NodePoint::operator<(const NodePoint&)’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define `operator<` on `NodePoint`, so that your node pairs can be ordered (`std::pair<NodePoint, NodePoint>` automatically defines `operator<` for you, in terms of `NodePoint::operator<`)

Presumably you want something like:

```
bool operator <(const NodePoint &rhs) const {
    return (x < rhs.x || (x == rhs.x && y < rhs.y));
};
```

**EDIT** Added `const`

Comment: I added your code to the NodePoint class but still i am getting some error on compiling

Comment: I added `const`, try now. Your other operators should be `const` as well (i.e. `bool operator == (const NodePoint &rhs) const { /* */ }`)

Answer (score 1):

In order to use `std::map`, the third template parameter defaults to `std::less<KeyType>` and thus your class has to provide `operator<` or its own comparator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the < operator for you map key as one of these

1. member - not possible in your case
2. global (or namespace scoped),

   typedef std::pair < NodePoint, NodePoint > NodePointPair;

   bool operator<(const NodePointPair&, const NodePointPair& ) { .... }

3.- As a functor - and then the 3rd paremeter in the map with the name of your functor. Exercise for the reader.

Comment: comparison operators are defined on `std::pair<T1,T2>` automatically [(link)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) as long as you they are defined on `T1` and `T2`.

Comment: @Lin You are right, there is a < operator for std::pair<T1,T2>.

Comment: @n00b The minimum work that you need to do is to define the following:     `bool operator < (const NodePoint& lhs, const NodePoint& rhs) { ... }`    for your program to work.